# How can I take a snapshot of a wep page's DOM structure?

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to compare a webpage's DOM structure at various points in point. What are the ways to retrieve and snapshot it.

I need the DOM on server-side for processing.

I basically need to track structural changes to a webpage. Such as removing of a div tag, or inserting a p tag. Changing data (innerHTML) on those tags should not be seen as a difference.

Comment: Do you need to return the DOM to the server-side?

Comment: Also, do you just need the HTML or really really the whole DOM? And do you need to capture the DOM from current browser page or is it sufficient to re-request the page by its URL?

Comment: I need the DOM, it needs to be data agnostic.

Comment: What do you mean by "data agnostic"?

Comment: Data agnostic as in not caring about data. I only need to compare the structure. Not the entire HTML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the following steps on server-side:

- Retrieve a snapshot of the webpage via HTTP GET
- Save consecutive snapshots of a page with different names for later comparison
- Compare the files with an HTML-aware diff tool (see [HtmlDiff tool listing page on ESW wiki](http://esw.w3.org/HtmlDiff)).

As a proof-of-concept example with Linux shell, you can perform this comparison as follows:

```
wget --output-document=snapshot1.html http://example.com/
wget --output-document=snapshot2.html http://example.com/
diff snapshot1.html snapshot2.html
```

You can of course wrap up these commands into a server-side program or a script.

For PHP, I would suggest you to take a look at [daisydiff-php](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/source/browse/trunk/daisydiff-php/HTMLDiff.php?r=113). It readily provides a PHP class that enables you to easily create an HTML-aware diff tool. Example:

```
<?
require_once('HTMLDiff.php');
$file1 = file_get_contents('snapshot1.html');
$file2 = file_get_contents('snapshot1.html');
HTMLDiffer->htmlDiffer( $file1, $file2 );
?>
```

Note that with `file_get_contents`, you can also retrieve data from a given URL as well.

Note that DaisyDiff itself is [very fine tool for visualisation of structural changes as well](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/wiki/CustomizingHtmlOutput).

Comment: I'd prefer not to make changes to the actual, rather retrieve them remotely and track the changes.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I changed my answer accordingly. The point is that the same approach applies also for server-side only processing.

Comment: PHP, I mentioned it as a tag, I guess I should've been more clearer.

Comment: I admire your dedication to help me out. Although I'm struggling with a weird 'No memory' error, I must say I'm now on the right track with this tool. Just a note though. The actual parsing syntax for that tool is `HTMLDiffer->htmlDiffer( $file1, $file2 );`

Comment: Thank you for the syntax correction. I wish you good luck with this work. Also, please ask for additional details or open a new question if you got into trouble again!

Answer (score 4):

```
$html_page = file_get_contents("http://awesomesite.com");
$html_dom = new DOMDocument();
$html_dom->loadHTML($html_page);
```

That uses PHP DOM. Very simple and actually a bit fun to use. [Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

EDIT: After clarification, a better answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871705/how-can-i-take-a-snapshot-of-a-wep-pages-dom-structure/3871790#3871790).

Comment: Nice! How then do I compare two DOM objects?

Comment: I basically need to track structural changes to a webpage. Such as removing of a div tag, or inserting a p tag. Changing data (innerHTML) on those tags should not be seen as a difference.

Comment: You should update your question with this data, then, because that goes beyond what you originally have in there. I can easily tell you how to retrieve the DOM, but I'm at a loss of an easy way for you to compare the DOM. I would likely end up iterating over it myself in a recursive function based off the last instance.

Comment: @Codeacula: maybe an "easy" way to compare the DOM would be to iterate through DOM, output the nodes in plain text format, and then use a diff?

Comment: If you don't get an answer, a 'simple' way would be to use a readily available tool like `diff` and load the output into the program.

Comment: @MainMa Got me in between answering. They wouldn't even need to go through the DOM, just load the site using `file_get_contents` and compared with the last saved version.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Why? I can't fix the answer if you ninja in a downvote and leave like an AC off to another question.

Comment: @Codeacula: if I understand well the original question, it *is* required to pass through the DOM, since only structure, and not the HTML is compared; the the contents of the elements don't matter. In other words, there is no difference between `<div>Hello</div>` and `<div>Hello World!</div>`, but there is a difference between `<div>A</div>` and `<div><span>A</span></div>`.

Comment: Duh. I totally forgot that stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use firefox, firebug lets you view the DOM structure of any web page.

Comment: I know, but I need to implement in an application and process it.